# DevOps YAML build pipeline multi-repo trigger branch not identified by Release Pipeline for continuous deployment trigger or artifact filter

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a YAML build pipeline which resides on the repo `PipelineRepo`, branch `master`.

It contains a reference to a second repo `AppRepo` with a trigger on branch `dev`.

When a commit is made on `AppRepo/dev`, the build triggers and produces an artifact. The `Build.SourceBranch` predefined variable available during the build is of course `dev` as this was the triggering branch on `AppRepo`. This is as per the docs here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#triggers

The specific part of the docs is this:

> When an update to one of the repositories triggers a pipeline, then
> the following variables are set based on **triggering repository**:
>
> - Build.Repository.ID
> - Build.Repository.Name
> - Build.Repository.Provider
> - Build.Repository.Uri
> - **Build.SourceBranch**
> - Build.SourceBranchName
> - Build.SourceVersion
> - Build.SourceVersionMessage

I consume the artifact in a Release pipeline, where I have a "Dev" stage with an artifact filter for branch `dev`:

[image]

I have a continuous deployment trigger on the artifact for branch `dev`:

[image]

### Now we come to the problem

Every time a new build artifact is produced from the `AppRepo/dev` branch, the continuous deployment trigger doesn't fire because it thinks the build branch of the artifact was `PipelineRepo/master`. This is also true of the artifact filter on the stage - I have tested it by changing the continuous deployment trigger to `master`.

*Note: you can see on the screenshot the build name contains the word "dev". This is because I use the `Build.SourceBranch` var in my custom build name. This proves the artifact is definitely produced by the `AppRepo/dev` triggering branch.*

[image]

### How can I get the DevOps Release Pipeline to pick up the triggering branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, I could reproduce the similar issue in my organization.

When the pipeline is triggered by another repo branch, it still show the master branch in Release artifacts.

At the same time,  the display of the trigger branch is also inconsistent in Pipelines.

For example:

**Overview:**

[image]

**Detail view:**

[image]

I suggest that you could create a feedback ticket in [Our feedback Site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=problem).

**For a workaround:**

You could add a build tag in Pipeline to distinguish artifacts.

Yaml sample:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: test
    type: git
    name: 123/ARM
    trigger:
    - test

steps:
- checkout: test
- script: echo  "##vso[build.addbuildtag]$(Build.SourceBranch)"
```

Release Pipeline:

You could set the master branch and add the build tag.

[image]